# Laravel - Is my double submission solution efficient

Tags: php, laravel

This my first question so please go easy on me. I have been using Laravel for a while; however, recently I have came across an issue in a client application while I was testing it.

The issue was if a user double submit or simply **clicked submit button x times then the same record will be created x times in the database**.

I have never faced this issue before simply because simple unique validation would achieve this.

**Nevertheless, this form (or model to be exact) allows data with the same values/duplicates (client app requirement).**

So the first thing I did was as follow:

```
public function store(CustomRequest $request)
{
    if($lastEntry = Record::latest()->first()){
        if(
            ($request->name == $lastEntry->name)
            && ($request->another == $lastEntry->another)
            //  && ($request->user()->id == $lastEntry->user_id) // Current user check (need to modify the $lastEntry for it to work efficiently!)
            && (now()->diffInMinutes($lastEntry->created_at) < 5) // I added this later as another way to allow duplicates records after each other if they were created 5m apart
        ){
            return redirect()
                    ->route('show.record', $lastEntry->id)
                    ->with('success', 'Record has been created successfully.');
        }
    }

    $record= new Record();
    ....
}
```

Now, after testing, it works great. But, my question is, are there any built-in solutions for this, packages or simply better ones?

Also, should I do a session solution for faster response - because, correct me if I am wrong but won't this be slow if it was on a table with > 500k records?

Edit: I thought about making a custom throttle middleware for this, but it would be kinda a bad idea, what do you think?

Also, as mentioned by @nice_dev with more users a double would occur so I thought about adding the user_id field in the record table and grabbed the last record the current user created but still I think it is a bad solution.

**Javascript solution won't cut it unfortunately**

**Edit: What I meant by Javascript solutions, is the famouse once the button is clicked disable it kind of solution (any client-side solutions).**

BTW, the client application will eventually have more than 500k record per table (at least in the first year or so).

Feel free to modify my question as you like ... like I said I am new here!.

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe using CSRF? once is submitted, you can't send another one time the same CSRF so the second request will be dismissed?

Comment: Laravel has CSRF built in. However, I think CSRF is misunderstood it is used to identify who submitted the request and nothing else. It is not a spam solution that is why people use captcha and/or throttle middle wares :D  Thanks for your reply!

Comment: "Cross-site request forgery, also known as one-click attack or session riding and abbreviated as CSRF or XSRF, is a type of malicious exploit of a website where unauthorized commands are transmitted from a user that the web application trusts" - Wikipedia

Comment: What is meant by _javascript solution won't cut it unfortunately_?

Comment: Unless you're in a "no JavaScript" environment, it'll actually be a big help; you can disable the submit button once it's clicked.

Comment: Like when a button is clicked disable it kinda solution. It would be a client-side solution and not what the client wants or me IMO.

Comment: Also, your current solution doesn't really solve the problem since other users can make entries at the same time from their machines. So `latest()` will not necessarily give same result and user might still submit again. So just disable the submit button until request finishes. You might want to use some kind of session variables to make it more robust.

Comment: Exactly,  @nice_dev it is not perfect whatsoever. That is why I'm here :D

Comment: @nice_dev How about if I added a field in the table containing a unique identifier for the user and grabbed the last record the current user (submitter) created, you think it will be an improvement? It will come with a cost but better?

Comment: @Ali I would need more context if you are trying to create unique records per user. Unique identifier won't be needed if you have user ID as a foreign key in the record table assuming user and record are connected in some way.

Comment: @nice_dev of course it will be might as well make it a relationship in Eloquent. What I meant is rather than using  Record::latest()->first() I would get the last record created by the current user as an example: Record::where('user_id', $request->user()->id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first() ... allowing a user to enter the same record after 5m or whatever the client accept.

Comment: @Ali Ok so allowing duplicate entries after 5 mins is fine? Your question seems different now.

Comment: @Ali You can create indexing on FK column to improve performance.

Comment: @nice_dev read my code above (I added this later as another way to allow duplicates records after each other if they were created 5m apart) I have put that in my code the first submission. The issue is not duplicates in the context of duplicates but rather than adding the same record more than once by a user by mistake. The client required that and I have to do whatever he asks! He needs that for some type of analysis I personally do not get it, but it is what it is!

Comment: @nice_dev great idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, my situation is kinda unique I went with the same solution but added a user_id column on the records table (FK). And checked if the same record was created by the same user in the last x minutes (Since the client wants duplicate records but not allowing mistakes by the users).

Nevertheless, I added a javascript code to disable the button just in case. The client asked for a back-end solution not a client-side one. But might as well add that since I kinda solved the issue (kinda). Also, I created an indexing on the FK column as suggested by @nice_dev.

I had to come up with a solution fast. However, feel free to give your ideas/solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: i've not understand why you have refused the CSRF solution (i know that this is not its purpose, but i think it will work, since the user in order to get a new CSRF) but i would suggest to use `DB::begin() && DB::commit()` at the beginning and at the end of your code in order to use transactions, and so not to rely on timing to check if the FK & ID exists already

Comment: If you had been able to rely on JS alone, I would say that a confirmation dialog would have been a big help to reduce accidental submissions.

Comment: @Berto99 the transactions idea seems interesting not sure if it will work. But will try it when I can. I had to go with a fast solution yesterday because a demo with a fix was requested. Regarding the CSRF solution, the form I am using is POST and have \@csrf input as well as having the route set to POST only. So CSRF exists already but like I said it does not work as you think. I appreciate you and everyone who tried to help.